# Grid Filter for Milestine and display color not working

Tags: rally

Can anybody help me get Milestone and Displaycolor work in My grid filter?
I am able to get Milestone and DisplayColor in filter box but they are not working. The filter is not applied to grid
Thanks
HSG

```
this.add({
                        xtype: 'rallygridboard',
                        context: context,
                        modelNames: modelNames,
                        toggleState: 'board',
                        stateful: false,
                        plugins: [
                            {
                                ptype: 'rallygridboardinlinefiltercontrol',
                                inlineFilterButtonConfig: {
                                    stateful: true,
                                    stateId: context.getScopedStateId('filters'),                                    
                                    modelNames: modelNames,
                                    inlineFilterPanelConfig: {
                                        quickFilterPanelConfig: {
                                            defaultFields: ['ArtifactSearch'],
                                            addQuickFilterConfig: {
                                                whiteListFields: whiteListFields
                                            }
                                        },
                                        advancedFilterPanelConfig: {
                                            advancedFilterRowsConfig: {
                                                propertyFieldConfig: {
                                                    whiteListFields: whiteListFields
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                ptype: 'rallygridboardfieldpicker',
                                headerPosition: 'left',
                                modelNames: modelNames,
                                stateful: true,
                                stateId: context.getScopedStateId('columns-example')
                            },
                            {
                                ptype: 'rallygridboardactionsmenu',
                                menuItems: [
                                    {
                                        text: 'Print...',
                                        handler: function () {
                                            this.down('rallygridboard').getGridOrBoard().openPrintPage({ title: 'Program Board' });
                                        },
                                        scope: this
                                    }
                                    //
                                ],
                                buttonConfig: {
                                    iconCls: 'icon-export'
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        cardBoardConfig: {
                            plugins: [
                                { ptype: 'rallyfixedheadercardboard' },
                                { ptype: 'rallycardboardprinting' }
                            ],
                            readOnly: true,
                            rowConfig: {
                                field: 'Project'
                            },
                            columns: columns,
                            attribute: 'Iteration'
                        },
                        storeConfig: {
                            fetch: ['Iteration', 'Name', 'StartDate', 'EndDate']
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Hmm, what version of AppSDK are you using?  2.1 I assume?  Is it throwing any console errors at all?

Comment: 2.1 and its not throwing any error

Comment: Hi @KyleMorse did you get a chance to look into the issue.

Comment: forgot to add whiteListFields = ['Milestones', 'DisplayColor'];

Comment: did some research and saw the data passed in query is DisplayColor='#21A2E0' but it should be DisplayColor='#21a2e0' i.e it should be in lowercase instead it is going in upper case